# How to enable CORS headers in api gateway through SpecRestApi

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I would like to enable API Gateway CORS through SpecRestApi. i have tried enabling through extension but i get this error

`failed to deploy: UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE: Resource handler returned message: "Errors found during import: Unable to put integration response on 'OPTIONS' for resource at path '/products': Invalid mapping expression specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid mapping expression specified: Access-Control-Allow-Header] (Service: ApiGateway, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 2d40bd8e-6eda-4482-98f4-fdb8188179ee)"`

any idea how can I fix this error or enable CORS?

here is how I added the extension to my API specification

```
const apiSpec = parse(fs.readFileSync(path.resolve("api-spec.yaml")).toString());

apiSpec.paths[path]['options'] = {};
          apiSpec.paths[path]['options']['x-amazon-apigateway-integration'] = {
            type: 'mock',
            requestTemplates: {
              'application/json': '{ "statusCode": 200 }',
            },
            responses: {
              default: {
                statusCode: '200',
                responseParameters: {
                  'gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '\'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,X-Api-Key\'',
                  'gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '\'OPTIONS,POST,GET\'',
                  'gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '\'*\''
                },
                responseTemplates: {
                  'application/json': '{ "statusCode": 200 }'
                }
              }
            }
          }
```